# How can I sync cronjobs from one server to another?

Tags: linux, crontab

What is the configuration file that defines the cronjobs?

I know you can `crontab -e`, but it points to a temporary file.

Comment: I’ve forgotten the exact path, and I don’t have a Linux system handy to check, but try looking under `/var/cron`.  Alternatively, do `man cron` and `man crontab` and see whether they tell you.

Comment: I think it is `/var/spool/cron/`. In this directory all users crontab lists are stored. My system is CentOS6.3. The path may vary in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are kept in

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

However, this does require root access by default.

You should never edit these files manually. This can cause all sorts of issues but it should be possible to sync them.